# SQL Server 2008/2012 Not parsing XML Soap

Tags: sql-server, xml, soap, sqlxml

Oh, what a day.  I am trying to parse Some XML in SQL Server and have done it before with some very huge files, but with these ones, I am having the utmost problem.  I actually did a recursive parse through the XML so that I could properly identify all of the nodes, so I do know that I am not crazy.

My code is this.

```
DECLARE @XML XMl

SELECT @XML = xmldata from testing where testingID = 3

select T.c.value('Legs[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Legs
/*t.c.value('(PoolId)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [Pool],
t.c.value('(./Model/@id)[1]', 'int') ModelID,
t.c.value('(./Note)[1]', 'varchar(100)') Note,
t.c.value('(./Part)[1]', 'varchar(15)') Part*/
from @xml.nodes('/Envelope/Body/GetEventDetailResponse/EventsResponse/EventDetail/Races/Race/Pools/Pool') as T(c)
```

I left in some old code which I know works on the old XML files with no problem but commented that out.

The XML is this

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
  <GetEventDetailResponse xmlns="http://schema.unitedtote.com/ToteLink/2008/06/Program">
     <EventsResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <RunId xmlns="http://schema.unitedtote.com/ToteLink/2008/06/Common">2613</RunId>
        <GroupId xmlns="http://schema.unitedtote.com/ToteLink/2008/06/Common">TH1</GroupId>
        <Source xmlns="http://schema.unitedtote.com/ToteLink/2008/06/Common">
           <SystemId>TSG</SystemId>
           <SourceId>TH1TST</SourceId>
        </Source>
        <EventDetail>
           <Races>
              <Race>
                 <Pools>
                    <Pool>
                       <PoolId>WIN</PoolId>
                       <PoolNumber>1</PoolNumber>
                       <PoolName>Win</PoolName>
                       <PoolRaces>1</PoolRaces>
                       <Legs>1</Legs>
                       <Quick>true</Quick>
                       <Box>true</Box>
                       <SingleBetMinimum>2</SingleBetMinimum>
                       <MultipleBetMinimum>2</MultipleBetMinimum>
                       <WagerMinimum>2</WagerMinimum>
                       <Maximum>10000</Maximum>
                       <Probables>true</Probables>
                       <WBMaximum>10000</WBMaximum>
                       <Straight>true</Straight>
                    </Pool>
                    <Pool>
                       <PoolId>PLC</PoolId>
                       <PoolNumber>2</PoolNumber>
                       <PoolName>Place</PoolName>
                       <PoolRaces>1</PoolRaces>
                       <Legs>1</Legs>
                       <Quick>true</Quick>
                       <Box>true</Box>
                       <SingleBetMinimum>2</SingleBetMinimum>
                       <MultipleBetMinimum>2</MultipleBetMinimum>
                       <WagerMinimum>2</WagerMinimum>
                       <Maximum>10000</Maximum>
                       <WBMaximum>10000</WBMaximum>
                       <Straight>true</Straight>
                    </Pool>
                    <Pool>
                       <PoolId>EX</PoolId>
                       <PoolNumber>4</PoolNumber>
                       <PoolName>Exacta</PoolName>
                       <PoolRaces>1</PoolRaces>
                       <Legs>2</Legs>
                       <Quick>true</Quick>
                       <Wheel>true</Wheel>
                       <Box>true</Box>
                       <PowerBox>true</PowerBox>
                       <KeyWheel>true</KeyWheel>
                       <SingleBetMinimum>2</SingleBetMinimum>
                       <MultipleBetMinimum>1</MultipleBetMinimum>
                       <WagerMinimum>2</WagerMinimum>
                       <Maximum>10000</Maximum>
                       <WBMaximum>10000</WBMaximum>
                       <Straight>true</Straight>
                    </Pool>
</Race>
           </Races>
           <EventId>XVD</EventId>
           <RunId>2613</RunId>
           <EventName>Vaal</EventName>
           <TrackId>XV</TrackId>
           <TrackName>Vaal</TrackName>
           <EventTime>2015-04-02T16:30:00</EventTime>
           <EventInfo>2 Apr 15</EventInfo>
           <EventType>Current</EventType>
           <TrackType>Thoroughbred</TrackType>
           <CurrencyId>USD</CurrencyId>
           <EventStatus>Open</EventStatus>
           <RaceList>1-8</RaceList>
           <BreakTo>0.1</BreakTo>
        </EventDetail>
     </EventsResponse>
  </GetEventDetailResponse>
```

This would be a lot more effective than writing out a parsing routine at the script level.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify namespaces, like this:

```
;with xmlnamespaces(
    'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as s,
    default 'http://schema.unitedtote.com/ToteLink/2008/06/Program'
)
select
    T.c.value('Legs[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Legs
from @xml.nodes('s:Envelope/s:Body/GetEventDetailResponse/EventsResponse/EventDetail/Races/Race/Pools/Pool') as T(c)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4041)</kbd>**